# Rails form_tag does not send params if disabled: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) in my view and a few [text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) nested in it. I do not want the user to edit the text fields so I did :disabled => true.

The problem:
If I do :disabled => true the text field value is not passed in params hash, while if I do :readonly => true it does send the values in params hash

Is this expected? If yes then there is no mention of this in the documentation. If not, then should I file a issue in GitHub?

Comment: Yes. Its the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected behavior. It is probably not mentioned in the Rails documentation because the `disabled` and `readonly` control behavior is defined by the W3C spec.

See the [W3C documentation for Disabled controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled), which states "disabled controls cannot be successful". A "successful" control is defined as being "'valid' for submission." Setting `disabled` to `true` on an input field in Rails will not cause it to not be submitted.

Read-only controls, however, can be successful. Therefore, if you wanted the value to be submitted, but not editable, you should use `readonly` set to `true`.

Comment: Worth noting that, according to Mozilla, `readonly` is "ignored if the value of the type attribute is hidden, range, color, checkbox, radio, file, or a button type (such as button or submit)."

Comment: But in case of select_tag it wont help.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is expected, but it has nothing to do with Rails. Per the HTML5 spec, form fields that are `disabled` are skipped when the form is submitted (see [4.10.22.4 Constructing the form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set)).

If you don't want the user to be able to edit the field, but still want its data to be submitted with the form, you should use the `readonly` attribute, e.g.:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'year', '2015', readonly: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert inside your form an `hidden_field` that will catch the value and will assign it to the form.

```
 <%= form.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id %>
```

Comment: Adding on to the above point, if you are using form_tag instead of form_for, below hidden_field tag can be used.

`<%= hidden_field_tag :name, value %>`